# JavaFX - Listener on LineTo

Tags: javafx-2, javafx, listener

i have  sth. like:

```
Path path= new Path();

MoveTo moveTo = new MoveTo();
moveTo.setX(390);
moveTo.setY(165);

LineTo lineTo = new LineTo();
lineTo.setX(235);
lineTo.setY(130);

path.getElements().add(moveTo);
path.getElements().add(lineTo);
path.setStrokeWidth(5);
path.setStroke(Color.BLACK);

field.getChildren().add(path);
```

Now I want to add a Listener to the Line I drew - I thought about 2 possibilities:

first: I can add somehow a Listener to lineTo

second: I can add somehow a Listener to the Area of the Line (a Hitbox from (390,165) to (235,130) with the width of 5px)

Can you tell me how I could do this? I am new with JavaFX and I got no idea.
In the end it should be possible to click on a line to change the color.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`LineTo` is only a logical element. The actual graphical entity is `Path` which can be enhanced with listeners:

```
    path.setOnMouseClicked(new EventHandler<MouseEvent>() {

        @Override
        public void handle(MouseEvent t) {
            path.setStroke(Color.RED);
        }
    });
```

Comment: Thank you - nearly seems to work - but i still have one question: How can i access path in the inner class when it isn't final? Or is there no way i could do this?